# How can I collect and use the Listbox values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, listbox, pysimplegui

How do I collect value in a listbox (`sg.Listbox`)? That is, when I select that line of the listbox (listbox 2, for example) with what parameters do I make the conditional?

For example:

```
[sg.Listbox(values=('Listbox 1', 'Listbox 2', 'Listbox 3','Listbox 4', 'Listbox 5'), key="_LISTBOX_"], [sg.Button('Option')]]

while True:             # Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
if event == 'Option':
    print(values) #here I see the values but I have no idea what to do. !!!! ????

    if values["_LISTBOX_"??????]: #??????????
        print("ok")
    window['-OUTPUT-'].update()
```

Answer (score 3):

To get information of selected items in `sg.Listbox`,

- Get values of selected items from `values['-LISTBOX-']`
- Get indexes of selected items from method `get_indexes` of `sg.Listbox`.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

value_list = [f'Listbox {i}' for i in range(1, 6)]
layout = [
    [sg.Listbox(value_list, size=(30, 5), font=("Courier New", 16), enable_events=True, key="-LISTBOX-")],
    [sg.StatusBar("", size=(30, 1), key='-STATUS-')],
]

window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
listbox, status = window['-LISTBOX-'], window['-STATUS-']

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    elif event == '-LISTBOX-':
        selection = values[event]
        if selection:
            item = selection[0]
            index = listbox.get_indexes()[0]
            status.update(f'Line {index+1}, "{item}" selected')

window.close()
```

Comment: Excuse me, thanks again, now one more step, ;-)
I need to fix an image inside a frame when activating a list for example (if index == 0 :)  and so when I activate any list I will insert a different image in that frame

Comment: Add more code `if index == 0: window['-IMAGE-'].update(filename=image_files[0])` or `window['-IMAGE-'].update(filename=image_files[index])` in block of `elif event == '-LISTBOX-'`, `window['-IMAGE-']` is the `sg.Image` element with option `key='-IMAGE-'` in your layout.

Comment: Thank you very much again, it has been a great help to me